# Get all public github repostories of user with javascript/node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

I want to get all public github repositories of given user from github.
I tried to make it with GET request [I read from here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/). When i try it with curl or in the browser everything is fine, but when I run this code is gives me http 403 status code

```js
var request = require('request');

request.get("https://api.github.com/users/:user")
    .on('response', function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

I tried using this [github api library](https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github), but couldn't work around the authetication

```js
var GithubApi = require("github");

var github = new GithubApi({});


github.authenticate({
    type: "oauth",
    token: "GIT_TOKEN"
});

var getUsersRepos = function (user) {
    github.repos.getAll({
        username: user
    }, function (err, res) {
        res.forEach(function (element) {
            console.log(`${element.name} - language: ${element.language} - issues: ${element.open_issues} - url: ${element.url}`);
        }, this);
    });
}

module.exports = {
    getRepos: getUsersRepos
};
```

But when I enter my token I can get only my user information.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong or some better idea will be appreciated

Comment: [_For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows you to make up to 60 requests per hour._](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) Did you maybe reach that limit?

Comment: I checked it now with GET /rate_limit - 54 requests remaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**The Github API requires requests to have a valid `User-Agent` header**](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required):

> If you provide an invalid User-Agent header, you will receive a 403
>   Forbidden response.

Github requests that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the `User-Agent` header value:

```
var request = require('request');

options =  {
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/:user",
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "tabula"  // Your Github ID or application name
    }
}

request.get(options)
    .on('response', function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

Comment: missing comma at end of your url line

Comment: @mjwatts: Thanks, fixed!

Comment: GitHub does explicitly request that you include your username or the name of your application as the `User-Agent` string: https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required